# DRY up turnip step definitions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, cucumber, dry

I know this is possible using cucumber by capturing optional groups (see [tip 3](http://coryschires.com/ten-tips-for-writing-better-cucumber-steps/) here), and I have it working in turnip, but I don't love the solution.

I am trying to eliminate multiple steps that are just positive/negatives of one another.

So instead of 2 steps like this:

```
step "I should see :content in the footer" do |content|
  within(".footer-main") do
    page.should(have_selector("h3", text: content)) 
  end
end

step "I should not see :content in the footer" do |content|
  within(".footer-main") do
    page.should_not(have_selector("h3", text: content)) 
  end
end
```

I can do this:

```
step "I should :not_text see :content in the footer" do |not_text, content|
  within(".footer-main") do
    not_text.blank? ? page.should(have_selector("h3", text: content)) : page.should_not(have_selector("h3", text: content)) 
  end
end
```

This works fine, but the thing I really don't like is that I have to put empty parenthesis in the positive scenario like so:

```
Scenario: User should see Company in the footer
    When I visit the "root page"
    Then I should "" see "Company" in the footer
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

How about using the following step definition:

```
step "I :should_or_not_text see :content in the footer" do |should_or_not_text, content|
  within(".footer-main") do
    should_or_not_text == "should" ? page.should(have_selector("h3", text: content)) : page.should_not(have_selector("h3", text: content)) 
  end
end
```

Then the feature looks a tiny bit cleaner:

```
Scenario: User should see Company in the footer
    When I visit the "root page"
    Then I "should" see "Company" in the footer
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK - this should work:

```
step "I should (not )? see :content in the footer" do |not_text, content|
  within(".footer-main") do
    not_text.blank? ? page.should(have_selector("h3", text: content)) : page.should_not(have_selector("h3", text: content)) 
  end
end
```

And then:

```
Scenario: User should see Company in the footer
    When I visit the "root page"
    Then I should see "Company" in the footer

Scenario: User should not see City in the footer
    When I visit the "root page"
    Then I should not see "City" in the footer
```

Answer (score 0):

```rb
step 'I should:not see :text' do |negative, text|
  expect(page).to(negative ? have_no_text(text) : have_text(text))
end

placeholder(:not) do
  match(/ not/) do
    true
  end
end
```